# How to learn more about MySQL, Apache and .htaccess?

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, .htaccess

I'm a teenager and I just like computer programming and always like to teach myself various stuff to its greatest extent. For example, after I learned HTML, I jumped on to learn HTML5, and after learning JavaScript, I began learning about closures, DOM, etc.

Recently, I was looking at some jobs posted on some popular sites (tumblr, vimeo) and I found out that **database-engineering** was listed and they were asking for one who knows **MySQL taken to its greatest extent**. What do they mean by this? I only knew that databases were used to store information and since I know PHP, I only used to query databases and that was it. So, how do I learn cool stuff these guys were mentioning on their site.

Secondly, I also want to learn about **how apache works** (even develop on it if there's something like it) and master **.htaccess** (htaccess is something about which I completely don't know anything).

Lastly, those sites (aforesaid) also mentioned that they were looking for a **linux developer**. What do they mean by this?

So, in straightforward way I want to master the LAMP stack and even go beyond the knowledge of the basics so that I can have a right to truly call myself a programmer.

Comment: Consider installing Linux on your computer (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian, Mint, ...).

Comment: Don't forget to experiment several programming languages (e.g. Scheme, Ocaml, Python, Common Lisp) and to read more "theoretical" books, e.g. http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, primarily databases are used to store the information. But there are various aspects related to database designs, development, administration, reporting, Integration services,
analysis services and Business Intelligence which fall under database engineering.

You can start with Headfirst SQL Ebook first..

Answer (score 1):

A Linux developer is someone who works on a Linux operating system. (Like windows or osx).

You should setup a [dual boot environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) or setup an Ubuntu (a version of linux) VM and practice on that. Learn the ways of the command line.

Get ubuntu from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Here's a guide for setting up a virtual machine:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11287/how-to-run-ubuntu-in-windows-7-with-vmware-player/

Once you have that running you can setup a LAMP, see this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

To learn about apache its best to google specifically what you are trying to get done. The apache.org pages are good.

Here is their breakdown of the .htaccess file:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Finally, to learn about MySQL you can check this out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tutorial.html

Comment: Why the hint of using Linux in a VM? I would rather suggest installing Linux on the laptop and using it daily (using Windows only for games).

Comment: i think its easier to do the VM, especially if you haven't heard about linux before

Comment: I believe that, specially for teenagers who learn quickly, installing linux and using it for everything, is the best (BTW, I never installed Windows on my PC -either at work or at home; my first Linux kernel was 0.99.15 on SLS).

Comment: yea I completely agree, however in order to do that you need to learn how to format, I thought installing a VM would be more straightforward and less error prone.